# ASPNETCOMPILER - Access related error on build server

Tags: .net, tfs, build, tfsbuild

I have two different build definitions for different projects.
Both of them are CI build definitions

While it executes successfully for one project, it fails for other project with the following error:

```
ASPNETCOMPILER: The current identity (MAIN\tfsbuild.tfsbs01) does not have write access to 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.
```

If this is an access related issue then how come one build definition works fine, and other doesn't?

Any guidance on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are both builds running on the same build server under the same identity?

Comment: yes, both builds running under same identity